# How to INDEX a through range of data and remove duplicates while using both MATCH and COUNTIF

Tags: excel

I have a range of data that I would like to have a formula return the title column detail based on three criteria in other columns and not repeat the result.  I have been able to use MATCH to set the criteria but have had trouble inserting COUNTIF into the formula to remove duplicates.  In summary, I would like to combine `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$10,MATCH(1,($H$2=C$2:C$10)*($H$3=$D$2:$D$10)*($H$4=$E$2:$E$10),0)),0)` and `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$10, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($G$8:G8,$B$2:$B$10), 0)),0)`.  I have provided the data and the results from the two formulas above.  Is it possible to combine the two formulas above to get the desired results shown below.  Hopefully returning the data in sequence along the row is not causing issues.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AGGREGATE to return the SMALL row number and COLUMN(A:A) to increment the *k* argument.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B:$B, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW($2:$10)/(($H$2=$C$2:$C$10)*($H$3=$D$2:$D$10)*($H$4=$E$2:$E$10)), COLUMN(A:A))), TEXT(,))
```

Answer (score 1):

With the new Dynamic Array functions (currently only available in Excel Insider Fast builds for some), this can be done with this formula:

```
=UNIQUE(INDEX(FILTER(B2:E11,(C2:C11=H2)*(D2:D11=H3)*(E2:E11=H4)),,1))
```

[image]

Mind you, this is just one formula in ONE cell. Nothing has been copied down. The formula automatically spills into the neighboring cells. If you want the results spread across columns, wrap the formula in Transpose()

[image]